# How to add an array of objects that I receive to an array inside of a struct?

Tags: struct, solidity

I am using Solidity with Hardhat and I am trying to loop through an array that I am receiving and adding it to an array that is inside of a struct. But I keep getting errors like:

```
Error: invalid address or ENS name (argument="name", value={"country":"United States","signature":"USA-123456","date":"5/6/2022"}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.6.2)
```

I have the following code in my Contract:

```
contract GlobalPassport {

event EmitPassportInfo(address[] citizenship);

    struct PassportInfo {
        address[] citizenship;
    }

    PassportInfo[] public citizen;

    function createNewPassport(address[] memory _citizenship) public {
        citizen.push(PassportInfo(_citizenship));

        emit EmitPassportInfo(_citizenship);
    }

}
```

And I am calling the function like this:

```
const person =  {
      citizenship: [
          {
              country: 'United States',
              signature: 'USA-123456', // global country code known to everyone
              date: timestamp
          },
          {
              country: 'Colombia',
              signature: 'COL-123456', // global country code known to everyone
              date: timestamp
          },
      ],
}

await globalPassportContract.createNewPassport(person.citizenship)
```

Could anyone point me in a good direction for this?

Comment: `createNewPassport` needs an array of addresses as argument. You are passing an array of structs.

Comment: @RiccardoS Im sorry but because of my lack of knowledge I don't fully understand, are you suggesting to stringify each object and send it that way? Although simply just strigifying the did work setting it to string[] citizenship;

Comment: Basically your {country, signature, date} struct can't be converted to address. So you should make a Solidity struct with these elements